# Различные типы fragmentmanager

Tags: android, fragment-manager

В Android есть несколько различных типов fragmentManager-ов: `parentFragmentManager`, `childFragmentManager`, `supportFragmentManager` и обычный `fragmentManager`, который уже deprecated. А в чём принциапиальные различия этих типов fragmentManager?

Answer (score 0):

Принципиальное отличие есть лишь между `deprecated` `fragmentManager` и остальными, т.к. он используется для фрагментов не из библиотеки поддержки.

Остальные - используются для фрагментов из библиотеки поддержки и отличаются только тем, что `childFragmentManager` - это внутренний `fragmentManager` фрагмента, а `parentFragmentManager` соответственно `fragmentManager` либо родительского фрагмента или родительской активити.